# UITableView endUpdates crash when called in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to modify it in viewDidLoad of my view controller.
But UITableView does not query its dataSource in viewDidLoad so I call reloadData first and then I modify its cells with beginUpdates and endUpdates. (In my case I'm just deleting some cells).
But when endUpdates is called it throws an exception:

> [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array.

what does this exception mean?
I know that I am returning correct numbers to UITableView because if I call it after viewDidAppear it works perfectly, it just doesn't work in viewDidLoad.

**EDIT :**

here's my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [customDataSource numberOfSectionsInTableView]; i ++) {
    NSInteger n = [customDataSource tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++)
        [array addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    [super beginUpdates];
    [super deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [super endUpdates];
}
```

when i move this code from viewDidAppear to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear it will crash.

Comment: Are you setting up your array before or after calling begin/end updates?

Comment: I'm setting up my array in applicationDidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions: of my appDelegate which is of course before viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Nothing in my viewDidLoad will show you how does this bug is happening. I have developed a custom tableview which is inherited from UITableView and I'm using this custom tableview in my view controller. then I have to post a dozen kbytes of code in here and I can't. What informaion exactly do you want to know?

Comment: All this doesn't seem to make much sense. It's controller code in a view class, begin/end updates should embrace the whole block, and then why delete anything on a view that hasn't even shown yet?

Comment: this code is not written directly in view controller. view controller just calls a method of a view class.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are trying to insert an object at index 1 into an empty array. If the array is empty, then the only acceptable index for insertion is 0. Check how you calculate the index values.